# Upside-down splash screen with Cocos2d

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, splash-screen

I'm using cocos2d v1.0.1 for the iPhone.  My app needs to support landscape left and right only.  I'm adding the splash image in a rotated portrait mode so when the splash image is removed I can load a background image that is identical to it and do some animations so it appears seamless.

The problem is the splash screen is ALWAYS upside-down in relation to the background image I add.  This is regardless of if my rotated portrait image is rotated left or right.

I'm using the default rotation code and setup for cocos.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: your code snippets will help here

Comment: It's difficult to add code here due to the images being added to the project's target UI.  Unless you want to see all of cocos2d's rotation code :)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to duplicate the image and name it differently. And use it as per your need instead of using the default.png. It caused problem with me also. Instead of wasting my time I just used this way. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Nikhil could you explain in a little more detail what you mean?